# Jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a code, where jquery is looking, where mouse is (hover/mouseover)

```
$(".hover tr").live("mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html("&nbsp;");    

});
```

For some reason, this is not working :(

Comment: Please specify what the code is supposed to do, and what it does instead. Also, do you get any error messages? "It is not working" does not mean much...

Comment: Try mouseout instead of mouseleave

Comment: What is that page/application site, where i can store code? Fishfile or something? I can put my code in there and i can show it to you better. The thing that code should do is, that it show Edit/Delete buttons when hover mouse over the row. But with @Teemu Laine answer it's working

Comment: That site is [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to input jquery script in the beginning of code.

Try this example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Put it inside the `<head>`tag

Comment: -.- I'm silly :'D i've forgot to input that script code. Thank you, now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because `live()` has been removed from jQuery as of 1.9 (and deprecated from 1.7); instead you should use the `on()` method:

```
$('.hover tr').on('mouseleave', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

This answer, of course, assumes you're using the latest incarnation of jQuery.

References:

- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

**As of jQuery 1.7**, the .live() method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Source from http://api.jquery.com/live

Read http://api.jquery.com/on